# Get Test method name in TestNG/Maven reporting in case of DataProvider running multiple tests with different data for single Test method

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, testng, rest-assured

I have a Test method in my Automation script that has to be run for 6 different people.
There is a custom DataProvider that provides those 6 people and method name is `getSalaryDetails()`. Execution is working perfectly fine and tests are running fine. Reporting is where the issue comes.

For these `6 Test runs` for a single method, results are being displayed as 6 times for `getSalaryDetails()` which is making difficult to understand the DataProvider for which the test would be failing.

Is there a way to implement in TestNG/Maven so i can get the Test method name by appending the parameter/Data provider somewhere so it would read somewhat like
`Person1getSalaryDetails()`
`Person2getSalaryDetails()` and so on..!

Here is the code that is being used for reporting

```
public class ReportListener implements ITestListener {


    //Extent Report Declarations
    private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.createInstance();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new ThreadLocal<>();


    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " started!"));
        //Start operation for extentreports.
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName(), result.getMethod().getDescription());
        test.set(extentTest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed!"));
        test.get().pass("Test passed" + result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " skipped!"));
        test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println(("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage for " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("Extent Reports Version 3 Test Suite started!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println(("Extent Reports Version 3  Test Suite is ending!"));
        extent.flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters passed by the data provider to test methods can be fetched in Listener methods as follows

```
@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " started!"));
    //Start operation for extentreports.
    String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
    if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
        methodName = parameters[0].toString + methodName;
    }
    ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(methodName, result.getMethod().getDescription());
    test.set(extentTest);
}
```

Another option is we can add the parameter from data provider method to test description from the test method.

```
@Test
public void testMethod(String personName) {
    ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    result.getMethod().setDescription(personName + " along with other string");
}
```

Comment: For your first solution, how do i get it in TestNG report. It's printing the name but how do i append it in TestNG function result window. @prakash

Comment: Well, you are using ExtentReport. You can use `test.get().info()`. If you use TestNG html report, `Report.log()` can help.

Comment: where to add this `report.log`, in listener?

Comment: Prakash Saravanan please see my answer

Comment: Prakash Saravanan this is not editing the console function list which uses TestNG i think. Can you check the SS i posted in my answer.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWVV.png) @prakash please check this link. this is where i want to get things right as well, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: No way that I know to alter the method name in console. We can do it in html report as I mentioned above. We can print the parameter in failure message to differentiate among other runs.

Comment: I found this link, but unable to implement it properly in my class. Can you go through and see if this can help. This is the exact requirement [editing method name in console] (https://www.swtestacademy.com/change-test-name-testng-dataprovider/)

Comment: any updates if you were able to figure out how to go about.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test(dataProvider = "inputData")
    public void testMethod(final Map<String, Object> dataMap){
    try{

        //Note: As you said you are using dataProvider every test run you will get the personName- add name like shown below line.
        //dataMap.get("personName") - input data from dataprovider
        extentTest = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString()+dataMap.get("personName"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        extentTest.log(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
```